# CSS Menu/Nav Bar: Centered Image, fluid width

Tags: html, css, menu, css-float

My goal is to produce a navigation/menu bar that has a centered image but shrinks to fit its content. The way I have it designed now, if the page shrinks, the `<li>` items that don't fit end up being pushed to the next line, making the nav bar taller. All li items and the image should shrink to keep the height of the nav container to its size, and only fill the page, not overflow.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/t5P7y/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav-ul">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li><img src="../Logo.png"></li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/t5P7y/6/

```
.nav-ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav-bar {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background:red;
}
.nav-ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:14.2%;
}
.nav-ul img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: well done! I spent over an hour messing with this. You win my CSS guru approval!

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the basic question of whether or not this is really a good design choice for a nav bar,
the only way I can think to achieve this without introducing javascript is to use percentage widths for each `<li>`, assuming the number of items in your list will not change

```
.nav-ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 14.28%;
}
```

Comment: I'd love your thoughts on why this is a poor design choice; the style of the logo is one which accommodates centered placement in my mind so the nav buttons logically flow on either side

Comment: What is the desired behavior if the window is very small? How will it degrade? Should the logo always have a minimum width?

Comment: When the window is very small a CSS selector hides the menu and it instead jumps to the bottom, having only one button - see here for a demo of the behavior I'm after http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/298_mobile_first_navigation/demo/index.html

Comment: I'm not saying this is the best way to approach it either I'm just sharing what logically made sense to me for my implementation. I'm all ears if you have a better idea ;)